# Forcing users to access the site with www. and https

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I am trying to write an .htaccess rule that appends www. to the domain and s to http if required but I can't seem to find a rule or set of rules that works for each case.

The cases are...

\https://www.site.com - should just work

\http://www.site.com - should go to \https://www.site.com

\http://site.com  - should go to \https://www.site.com

\https://site.com -  - should go to \https://www.site.com

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This should cover both cases in which either the request was not HTTPS (first condition) or the host does not start with `www.` (second condition). In that case the third condition will grab the host without the starting `www.` (if present) that is then used in the rule’s substitution.

Comment: No joy, I was getting an internal server error when I run this.

Comment: @Toby: What does the error log say? Did you use obligatory `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: OK, I was doing something daft to get that error, my bad.  

However it doesn't cover _https_://site.com to _https_://www.site.com

Comment: @Toby: Hm, that case should be handled too. The expression of the condition that leads to a redirect is `!https || !starts_with_www`. That means it should only not do a redirect if the opposite is the case: `!(!https || !starts_with_www)`. And that’s equal to `https && starts_with_www`. So I can’t see any mistake in my answer.

Comment: I have read in some places about an issue when sites use https:// that is caused by the redirect being blocked because the server automatically doesn't trust the connection, this could well be the case here.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Toby: Maybe HTTPS requests are handled by another virtual host or in another directory. You could try the opposite, redirect every HTTPS request to HTTP by replacing `!on` with `on` and `https://` with `http://`.